# Javascript text render error on update (webkit only)

Tags: javascript, css, dom, render

I'm trying to toggle text on click. When 'Pause' is clicked change the text to 'Play'.

For some reason the text is updating but not rendering correctly. It's as if that part of the DOM is being updated but not refreshed. For some reason this is only happening in the webkit browsers (Safari 5, Chrome 11). Firefox 4 is rendering it the way it should.

Here's a video of the problem: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIRKx25NmYo

I'm using Cmd+A in the video to select the text, which appears to refresh the text and get it to display properly.

Here's the code:

```
<span class="playercontrols" id="playpause" onclick="toggle(this.id);" style="cursor:pointer;">Pause</span>


<script type="text/javascript">

function toggle(sender){

var t = document.getElementById(sender);
var txt = t.innerHTML;

switch(txt) 
    {
    case 'Pause':
        txt = 'Play';
        pause();
        break;
    case 'Play':
        txt = 'Pause';
        play();
        break;
    default:
        txt = 'Pause';
    }           
t.innerHTML = txt;

}

</script>
```

EDIT: I commented out every other piece of javascript referenced and written on the page and the problem is still there. I have no idea what's wrong but it doesn't appear to be a collision or conflict.

---

SOLVED IT. (Not allowed to mark this answered because it's too recent.)

Edit: Answer now added below.

Thanks for all the comments. Hopefully this post will help others in the future with the same problem.

Comment: try to position your span tag in a different location

Comment: what do you mean by different location? I just took it out of the div it was in and moved it to the first line inside of the body tag. no effect.

Comment: What do `pause()` and `play()` do?

Comment: They play and pause a youtube video. The render error happens even without those function calls though.

Comment: @Zaqx, is the flash overlaid over the text (*transparently*) ?  or the opposite (*text overlaid on flash*) ?

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli no, I just figured it out. For some reason webkit has issues rendering the update if the element is positioned relatively.

Comment: This is a bit silly: first `onclick="toggle(this.id);"` and then `t = document.getElementById(sender);` Why not this: `onclick="toggle(this);"`

Comment: @Zaqx, answered with a workaround for this, so you do not have to change your styles..

Comment: @Rudie now I feel silly, didn't even realize you could do that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the styling on the "playercontrols" class.

```
.playercontrols {
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

I had it set to position relative which apparently sent webkit's update rendering out of whack.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that flashing the text (*setting `visibility` to `hidden` and then back to its original value*) fixes the issue..

So here is the work around.

```
t.innerHTML = txt;
/* add the following right after changing the text */
var visibility = t.style.visibility;
t.style.visibility = 'hidden';
setTimeout( function(){
    t.style.visibility = visibility;
}, 1);
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/SgwsZ/4/

Comment: Very flashy! haha couldn't resist. ;) Seriously though this looks like a pretty solid work around. I wish I could vote it up but apparently I need 15 reputation. :/  Thanks for your time on this!